# I will be inactive for at least one month

Tags: discussion, opinion-based

I will be inactive for one month after reading this Q&A https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392867/2777965 and perhaps I will leave SE.

Comment: I can just relate, take care of you, I know how draining that can be.

Comment: Ping as follow up, did you see the last activities on meta.se?

Comment: @Tensibai could you include a link?

Comment: I'd start with https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344178/the-q1-2020-community-roadmap-is-on-the-blog?cb=1 and the various featured posts on MSE :)